# AngularJS : using ng-repeat and ng-model to populate an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to use ng-repeat and ng-model in order to populate an array. The number of required elements in the array comes from a `select` element`.

The relevant part of my controller:

```
app.controller('AddMsgCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.range = function(n){
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            array.push(i);
        return array;
    };

    $scope.images = ['1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif', '4.gif', 'any.gif'];

    $scope.msg = { 'images': [] }
```

And the relevant part of my html:

```
Number of images:
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="numOfImages" ng-init="numOfImages=0">
    <option ng-repeat="number in range(6)" value="{{number}}">{{number}}</option>
</select>
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="n in range(numOfImages) track by $index">
        <select class="browser-default" ng-model= ???>
             <option ng-repeat="image in images" value="{{image}}">{{image}}</option>
        </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Right now the user can select the number of images they wish to input and the same amount of `select` elements shows up. I'm just not sure how to use `ng-model` to add the chosen elements to the `$scope.msgs.images` array.

**EDIT:** I was closer than I thought. This seems to work correctly:

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="msg.images[$index]">
     <option ng-repeat="image in images" value="{{image}}">{{image}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `msg.images[$index]`
[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3b73toJw6yoOG3j8OyxD?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
    Number of images:
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="numOfImages" ng-init="numOfImages=0" ng-options="number for number in range(6)" ng-change="updateImages()">

</select>
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="n in range(numOfImages) track by $index">
        <select class="browser-default" ng-model="msg.images[$index]" ng-options="image for image in images">
        </select>
   </div>
</div>

Msg : {{msg}}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.range = function(n){
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            array.push(i);
        return array;
    };

    $scope.images = ['1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif', '4.gif', 'any.gif'];

    $scope.msg = { 'images': [] };

    $scope.updateImages = function() {
      // alert($scope.numOfImages);
      $scope.msg.images.splice($scope.numOfImages, $scope.msg.images.length);
    }
```

Extra function is added which will execute on selecting the number of images. Once you select a number and if you want to reduce the number, the array size also should be decreased if you want. For that I added.

Comment: Check the updated HTML. You can use `ng-opttions` instead of using ng-repeat in options